# $f:\mathbb{Q} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, with conditions on $f$

Tags: functional-analysis, functional-equations

I would like to find all functions : $f:\mathbb{Q} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that :

1. $f(x) \geq 0$, $\forall x \in \mathbb{Q}$ and the equality holds only if $x = 0$
2. $f(x\cdot y) = f(x)\cdot f(y)$, $\forall x, y \in \mathbb{Q}$
3. $f(x+y) \leq\max\{f(x), f(y)\}$

Any suggestions, ideas ?

What I found :

- $f$ is even
- $f(x) = 1/f(1/x)$
- $f(kx) \leq f(x)$ with $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and $f(kx) \leq 1$

Comment: Have you already found that $f(0)=0$, $f(1)=1$, and $f(-1)=\pm 1$?

Comment: Partial comments:
$f(0)=0, f(\pm 1)=1,  f(n) \le 1\quad \forall n\in\mathbb N$
moreover $f(x) = f(-x)$ for every rational, and  $f(x) = 1/ f(1/x)$, so if you define it on the primes, you have defined it everywhere

Comment: Can we assume that the function is continuous?

Comment: Maybe relevant, "valuations" e.g. see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/889614/discrete-valuations-of-the-rational-numbers

Comment: A solution is $f(x)=1$ for $x \ne 0$ and $f(0)=0$

Comment: @Frpzzd it is certainly not continuous at $0$ since $f(2^{-n}) \geq 1$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: I thought a lot about the question and now I solved it but I cant post an answer since the question is on hold :(

Comment: @Nathanael That's a problem for any user wanting to answer a question that does not follow site guidelines. If the asker is willing to improve his/her question, and it's the first edit after its closure, users can vote to reopen, or keep closed.  Until then, I am pleased that you can't answer the question in its current state.

Comment: @amWhy I don't get it. You could at least mention whats wrong with this question. I read a lot idiotic question which got answered instead of closed. Would be nice in a math forum if there were some kind of consistency.
You are pleased that I can't share my knowledge eventhough there are obviously more people interested than the OP which is the only one who might have done something wrong. That sounds kind of sadistic.

Comment: @NathanaelSkrepek message was indeed left, about why it was closed and what can be done to improve it:  "Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level."

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2306826/is-there-a-continuous-non-constant-map-mathbbr2-to-mathbbs1?noredirect=1#comment4746463_2306826
can be closed too ;)
And i can find endless examples of that.

Comment: It's okay now I guess.

Comment: @NathanaelSkrepek Everyone is now waiting for your thoughts on the problem ;)

Comment: I will post it when I have a real keyboard, typing on my phone isn't fun

Answer (score 2):

Not quite an answer, but some probably significant facts about $f(x)$:

From the statement that $f(x+y) \le \max \{f(x), f(y)\}$ we can derive the statement
$$f(2x) \le f(x)$$
and so
$$f(3x) \le \max \{f(2x), f(x)\}$$
$$f(3x) \le f(x)$$
and, without loss of generality,
$$f(kx) \le f(x)$$
for any positive integer $k$. Furthermore, since $f(x)$ is even,
$$f(-kx) \le f(x)$$
for any positive integer $k$. This means that, since $f(1)=f(-1)=1$, for all integer $x$,
$$f(x) \le 1$$
Can you extend this statement to all rational $x$ greater than one?

Comment: The problem is that, for example, $f(1/2)f(2) = f(1) = 1$ so $f(1/n)\ge 1$ for your reasoning

Comment: Yes, I understand. Perhaps for all rational $x$ greater than $1$?

Answer (score 1):

### Some facts

> 1. $f(n) \leq 1$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$
> 2. $f(x^{-1}) = f(x)^{-1}$
> 3. $f(x)$ = $f(|x|)=|f(x)|$
> 4. $f(1)= 1$ and $f(0)=0$
> 5. If $x\neq 0$ and $f(x)\neq 1$ then there is a $p\in\mathbb{P}$ such that $f(p)<1$.

These facts aren't hard to varify.

### functions which satisfy all conditions

Note that for every $x\in \mathbb{Q}$ and every $p\in \mathbb{P}$ we find $m,n,k \in \mathbb{Z}$such that
\begin{align}
x = p^k \frac{m}{n} \quad \text{and}\quad \gcd(m,n)=1
\end{align}
Now we define $f_{p,c}:\mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{R},\; f(x) = f(p^k \frac{m}{n}) = c^k$ for $p\in\mathbb{P}$ and $c\in\mathbb{R}$. Note that if $x = \frac{m}{n}$ such that $p\nmid m$ and $p\nmid n$ then $f(x)=1$.

> The set of all functions which satisfy all your conditions is
>   \begin{align} M := \big\{f_{p,c} : p\in\mathbb{P} \text{ and } c\in (0,1]\big\} \end{align}

It is easy to check that every function in $M$ satisfies all conditions. So I want to prove the more interesting fact that there aren't more functions:

### There aren't more

If there is a $f:\mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{R}$ which satisfies all conditions and $f\notin M$ then we can conclude from fact point 5. that there are at least $p_1, p_2\in\mathbb{P}$ such that $f(p_1)<1$, $f(p_2)<1$ and $p_1>p_2$.

Now we do some kind of recursion, take
\begin{align}k_{i+1} := \max\{n\in\mathbb{N} : p_i-np_{i+1} > 0\} \quad\text{and}\quad r_{i+2} := p_i - k_{i+1} p_{i+1}\end{align}
If $f(p_{i})<1$ and $f(p_{i+1})< 1$ then $f(r_{i+2}) \leq \max\{f(p_{i}),f(k_{i+1}p_{i+1})\}< 1$ so there is either

- a primfactor $q$ of $r_{i+2}$ such that $f(q)<1$ or
- $r_{i+2}=1$

but the second case leads to $f(1)< 1$ which contradicts fact point 4. So there will always happen case 1 and we can define
\begin{align}
p_{i+2} := q
\end{align}
Clearly we have $0<p_{i+2}\leq r_{i+2}<p_{i+1}<p_{i}$ and $p_i \in \mathbb{P}$. Now we can show by induction that there are infinitely many prime numbers smaller than $p_1$ which is false and gives us a contradiction to our assumption that $f \notin M$ and $f$ satisfies all conditions.