# Given $x^5 \equiv 2 \pmod {2011},$ I need to solve for $x$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

How can I solve this equation?:

$$x^5 \equiv 2 \pmod{2011},\quad x \in \mathbb{N}$$

I mean, I don't see how can I solve it without using a computer...

Comment: J.OK  Time to learn and abide by site guidelines for good questions....See "help" tab, (open menu) and search for "asking: ["How to ask a good question"](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).  It's evident that you've missed this, or else you didn't care, since you have asked a lot of homework questions over the last 43 days, with no thoughts or demonstration of effort, from you.  That's a no-no.

Comment: You see, when you continue to ignore/avoid comments to the effect that, as an asker, more is expected of you than simply passing along homework questions to us, expecting us to do it  for you,  someone eventually catches on, and pays more attention to whether earlier questions you've asked are poor questions, too.

Comment: You are totally wrong. It's not homework question, but interesting problems. Moreover the only problems I asked is the functionnal equation and this one. Yet I didn't have any answer. So you are wrong a second time. And finally the probelm : "solving a modular equation", is an IMO kind of problem not a homework at all and I was wondering If there is way to solve it without using a calculator. Hence all your analyses is false, and you are just accusing without thinking which is a big mistake.

Comment: You never explained, J.OK, or answered to the fact that is was only after reviewing many of your past question, that I addressed this question partly because you've asked too many questions that are nothing more than problem-statements, and the guidelines apply to all such questions, whether homework or not.  As I see it, there are many good homework question, in which the asker explains what they've tried, or any demonstration effort. Your question is vulnerable to closure for lacking context, display of effort, identifying definitions and theorems that might apply, etc.

Comment: @amWhy Anyway, can you also alowed people to post on the post I've made on the functional equation ?

Comment: I'm not clear what you mean by "allow people to post"  on your question on the functional equation?  I haven't stopped anyone from answering any of your questions.  What functional equation are you referring to, J.OK?

Comment: One of the consequences when you write a question that fails to meet standards is that the question may be closed, and in your case, for lack of context, which I have already explained to you: it prevents any other potential answerers from answering such posts.  The only way around the "on hold/closed" status is to improve your question.  Only your first edit will trigger the review queue., so if the edit is not sufficient to reopen the question, any further edits will no longer bring your question to be reviewed, usually getting lost over time, or deleted as abandoned.

Comment: @amWhy OK but nothing is missing in my post on the functionnal equation : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2301686/f-mathbfq-rightarrow-mathbfr-with-conditions-on-f?noredirect=1#comment4744798_2301686

Comment: I have a good title, and everything is clear that's why a lot of people actually want to answer

Comment: J.OK I saw only one user mentioning wanting to answer.  I also saw a bare question, without any effort shown from you.  There's a reason such questions, until a proper edit from you (showing your efforts,  your thoughts on it etc), are closed: the question can no longer be answered.  If you want your question reopened, edit the question to  include the factors I have mentioned multiple times.  If you keep insisting that your question is fine (despite many users it is not), your question will remain on hold, perhaps closed.  I can't change that fact.

Comment: FYI, J.OK, This is not a question dump center : "insert (ask) question, output "full answer" site.  We expect askers to give more context, to put their own "2 cents worth" into solving a question, even if you got stuck along the way.  This is not a "do my homework/solve these problems for me" site.  If you don't want to follow site guidelines about asking a good question, and/or what is expected of users in their question,  then you're welcome to search other sites who handout answers, or sites that will help you at a cost to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not have to trial multiple exponents.

Begin by verifying that $2$ is a fifth power residue $\bmod 2011$.  This is done by showing that $2^{402}\equiv 1$ (all equivalence are understood here to be $\bmod 2011$).  Having certified that, conclude that

$2^{402m+1}\equiv 2$

For any whole number $m $.  But then the exponent $402m+1$ is a multiple of $5$ for $m=2$ leading to:

$2^{805}=(2^{161})^5\equiv 2$

so that  $x=2^{161}\equiv 1525$ is identified as one solution.

The other solutions are obtained from multiplication by a primitive fifth root of unity.  This would be any $402$nd power of a *non-fifth power* residue.  We have seen that $2$ is a fifth-power residue, but $3$ gives : $3^{402}\equiv 1328$.  Thus the solution is completed by successive multiplication of $1525$ by  $1328$.  After sorting the complete solution set is given by

$\{123, 295, 453, 1525, 1626\} $

Answer (score 1):

Without a computer it's a lot of work. (But I'd love to see a clever solution!)

The main point is that $2011$ is a prime and so the multiplicative group mod $2011$ is cyclic.

Thus, first you need to find a primitive root mod $2011$. There is usually a small one.

$2$ has order $402$ and so is not a primitive root, but $g=3$ is a primitive root.

If $a$ is a root of $x^5=2$, then all roots are of the form $au$, with $u^5=1$. The elements of order $5$ are $g^{402k}$ for $k=1,\dots,4$ and so $u=g^{402k}$ for $k=0,\dots,4$.

Therefore, you only need to find one root of $x^5=2$, which can be done by testing the powers of $g^5$; these contain the elements of order $402$. (You only have to test exponents coprime with $402=2 \cdot 3 \cdot 67$, still $132$ exponents.)