# Is there a continuous non constant map $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{S}^1$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, algebraic-topology

This must be very elementary but I couldn't recall the answer myself or find it in the web.

Is there a continuous non constant map $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{S}^1$?

Comment: Do you mean to impose some additional condition? What about $(x, y) \mapsto \exp(2 \pi i x)$?

Comment: If you don't care about $0$ then $x \mapsto \frac{x}{\|x\|_2}$

Comment: @NathanaelSkrepek **Of course** you are supposed to care about $0$: "topology" is a subject which is extremely susceptible to the removal of a point and, in fact, there is no continuous map $\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb S^1$ which extends yours.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli are you some kind of wizard or how do you know that OP really needs $0$ in the domain. Yes I can read and in his question there is $\mathbb{R}^2$ stated but maybe he is satisfied with $\mathbb{R}^2\backslash\{0\}$. Therefore I mentioned it but thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: @Travis You are right, of course. (I was implicitly thinking the map really should depend on the two variables, but this is not neede for what I have in mind, so your example counts, thanks.) BTW, it is still interesting to think whether there is an example which depend on both coordinates

Comment: @NathanaelSkrepek I indeed thought on your example, but am interested in maps from the full plane.

Comment: then you could do $x \mapsto \exp(\mathrm{i}\|x\|_2)$ or any other norm.

Comment: @AsafShachar If you want it to depend on both coordinates, take $(x,y) \mapsto \exp(2\pi i (x+y))$.

Comment: @EwanDelanoy Nice! We can play with $x$ and $y$ like $\exp (2\pi i (xy))$, $\exp (2\pi i (x^2 + y))$. +1 :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By covering space theory we know that any map from $\Bbb R^2$ to $S^1$ lifts to a covering space of $S^1$ since $\Bbb R^2$ is simply connected.

So if we look at the covering map $\Bbb R^1 \to S^1, t \mapsto exp(2\pi i\, t)$ we know that any map from $\Bbb R^2$ to $S^1$ can be factored through this map. This factorization is even unique up to the choice of a base point.

What do I want to say with this? Looking at the exponential map is a quite natural thing because we don't impose any restriction.

So any non constant map $\Bbb R^2$ to $\Bbb R$ gives a non constant map from $\Bbb R^2$ to $S^1$. And there are a lot. Like polynomials in $x$ and $y$ as in the comments and many more.